# Python requests NOT decoding gzip file

Tags: gzip, python-requests

I've found a number of questions about how to stop the python-requests package from decoding gzip responses but in my case I would like it to but it doesn't.

The headers from the response are below and I imagine there is something missing that means requests believes that the data is not gzipped - is there a way that I can convince it that the data is gzipped and get it to unzip it?

```
'content-length': '56185'
'x-amz-id-2': 'M+hA+/y9hrL1t4zuBajryQHmhr3lnaeDqdeE5gXwnOmEwgJI6QWbw/M51M0rx3+r'
'accept-ranges': 'bytes'
'server': 'AmazonS3'
'last-modified': 'Tue, 24 May 2016 00:25:37 GMT'
'x-amz-request-id': 'D2694ABDCA2417E2'
'etag': '"44b77ad22e8edc8f4fab543b3d16b500"'
'date': 'Tue, 24 May 2016 10:18:01 GMT'
'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256'
'content-type': ''
```

Comment: Why is `'Content-Type` empty`? Why is there no `Content-Encoding` header?

Comment: You would have to ask the authors of 'papertrailapp.com'.  I'm just trying to work around the problems with what I have.  FYI, I've tried playing around doing...

    r = request....
    r.headers['content-type'] = .....
    print(r.text)

hoping that explicitly adding headers to the 'response' would help.  But I've not managed to hit the magic combination so perhaps this doesn't work as other posts imply.

Comment: If you thing the response is encoded using gzip but the proper headers are missing, maybe you should contact the service authors. They should fix their server.

Comment: What page are you downloading? https://papertrailapp.com/ gives me all the html and the headers include ` 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'`

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do from Python:  
  
`headers = {"X-Papertrail-Token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx }  
    url = ("https://papertrailapp.com/api/v1/archives/2016-05-24/download")  
      
    with open('archive.tsv', 'wb') as handle:  
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)  
        print(r.headers)  
           if not r.ok:  
                print("It failed")  
      
            else:  
                print(r.text)  
`

Comment: Umm, been re-reading docs and now I'm wondering if I've misunderstood the Python-requests docs.  What I'm doing is downloading an acrhive file, a TSV file that has been zipped up to create a file name 'archive.tsv.gz'.  My assumption was that I could have requests automatically give me the output for 'archive.tsv' but is that wrong?  Is the idea that the server takes some data, gzips it to make the transfer faster and requests gunzips it back to  the original data?  So my original data was a gz file, and that is what requests gives me?

Comment: That is my understanding as well. Have you found a way to gunzip on the fly (without having to store the complete file on disk/in memory)?